# Correct Syntax to Pass Parameter from API to Function in PHP

Tags: php, postman

I am 2 days into learning PHP and frustratingly I am struggling to GET and use a parameter passed into my API.

I have read the [PHP $_GET documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), it didn't take long, and also a number of SO pages about $_GET.

My use case is simple. I want to retrieve a list of records from MySQL db if they have a modified date greater than the passed in date.  The function works if I hard code '2019-03-18 00:00:01' for example.

Using echo I can see I am getting the parameter.

In fact, copying the output from echo and using to update the function which I use in the argument returns the expected result.

I'm guessing this has been asked before but I can't find it.  All the examples I read seem more challenging i.e. multiple variables or challenges with the function etc.

I must have made a newb mistake somewhere.

```
<?php
//Returns Lab Results Modified after the passed in date
include_once 'db_functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

//Get JSON posted by Android Application
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {

    $json = $_GET['date'];
    echo $json;

    // commenting out the next two line results in
    // '2019-03-19 00:00:01' returning and not the json array.
    $json = '2019-03-18 00:00:01';
    echo $json;

    $mod = $db->getLabResultsModifiedAfter($json);

    $a = array();
    $b = array();

    if ($mod != false){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mod)) {       
            $b["ID"] = $row["ID"];
            $b["last_modified"] = $row["last_modified"];
            $b["LabRef"] = $row["LabRef"];
            array_push($a,$b);
            }
        echo json_encode($a);
    }

} else {
    // Fallback behaviour goes here
}
?>
```

I haven't developed the app side function yet. I am using postman to pass in date of '2019-03-18 00:00:01' i.e.  [this for local](http://localhost:8080/its/getlabresultsmodifiedafter.php?date=%272019-03-18%2000:00:01%27).

Comment: So what value is being posted by the Android application?

Comment: I haven't developed the app side function yet. I am using postman to pass in date of '2019-03-18 00:00:01' i.e. http://localhost:8080/its/getlabresultsmodifiedafter.php?date='2019-03-19 00:00:01'

Comment: The date you are passing in your URL does not following the format '2019-03-18 00:00:01'. Try navigating to this URL ... http://localhost:8080/its/getlabresultsmodifiedafter.php?date=2019-03-18%2000%3A00%3A01 ... I have URL encoded the date 2019-03-18 00:00:01 in the querystring. I can see that you comment shows a date query string starting with %27 which is the URL encoded single quote. You should only send the value in query string variables. Not the single or double quote string delimiters.

Comment: Thanks @asiby, it was the quote marks causing my issue. Newbie mistake it is. Also, yes the URL I sent wasn't accurate.  I had been using http://localhost:8080/its/getlabresultsmodifiedafter.php?date=%272019-03-18%202000:00:01%27

Comment: so much reading for just a couple of quotes!

Comment: Indeed. You are welcome. But again, you are new to PHP. Hopefully this helps everyone else who is learning PHP. Good luck with the rest of your learning process. You can close this question or mark it answered some how so that it does distract others trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer as provided by @aisby.  I was using quotes in the passed in parameter.

> The date you are passing in your URL does not following the format
>   '2019-03-18 00:00:01'. Try navigating to this URL ...
>   localhost:8080/its/… ... I have URL encoded the date 2019-03-18
>   00:00:01 in the querystring. I can see that you comment shows a date
>   query string starting with %27 which is the URL encoded single quote.
>   You should only send the value in query string variables. Not the
>   single or double quote string delimiters. – asiby 18 hours ago